# Understanding what a gradient vector is

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, scalar-fields

**Definition:** let $A$ be an open set in a Euclidean space $X$. Let $f : A \to \mathbb R$ be a real valued differentiable function. Then,for each $a \in A$, there is a unique vector $\nabla f(a) x \in X$ such that $f'(a) x = \langle \nabla f(a), x \rangle$ for all $x \in X$. The vector $\nabla f(a) \in X$ is called the **gradient** vector of $f$ at $a\in ..$

I still can't understand what the gradient is? For what purpose is it used?

Please if anyone can provide some intuition on it.

Comment: The gradient at a specific point $x$ points in the direction in which $f$ grows fastest from $x$, and its magnitude is how steep that growth is. For $X=\Bbb R$ this happens to be the usual derivative, which means the gradient is useful in higher dimensions in exactly the same way the derivative is useful in one dimension.

Comment: If you look at the contour plot of $f$, then the gradient gives the (opposite of) direction of the 'fall line' (as in skiing).

Comment: Also, using your definition, we can see immediately that the gradient of $f$ at a point $p$ is orthogonal to the level set $f(x) = f(p)$ of $f$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine a landscape, where $x$ is west-east, and $y$ is north-south. Let $f(x,y)$ be the height at that point. If we take the gradient of $f$, we get a function from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$. At $(x,y)$, $\nabla f(x,y)$ points "uphill"; that is, it points in the direction of steepest ascent.

This is useful for physics. If you have some kind of potential energy function, taking the gradient will get you the corresponding force field. For example, consider a point mass $M$ fixed at the origin, and a smaller mass $m$ elsewhere. The potential energy of the small particle is $U = -G \frac{Mm}{r}$. If you take the gradient, you'll get $\vec{F} = G \frac{Mm}{r^2}$, which corresponds* with the results from physics.

We have to convert to rectangular coordinates, take the gradient, then convert back to polar.

$$
\begin{align*}
U &= -G \frac{Mm}{r} \\
&= -G \frac{Mm}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2 + z^2}} \\
\frac{\partial U}{\partial x} &= G \frac{Mm}{2 (x^2 + y^2 + z^2)^{3/2}} \cdot 2x = G \frac{Mm \cdot x}{(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)^{3/2}} \\
\frac{\partial U}{\partial y} &= G \frac{Mm \cdot y}{(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)^{3/2}} \\
\frac{\partial U}{\partial z} &= G \frac{Mm \cdot z}{(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)^{3/2}} \\
\nabla U &= \left\langle \frac{\partial U}{\partial x}, \frac{\partial U}{\partial y}, \frac{\partial U}{\partial z} \right\rangle \\
&= G \frac{Mm}{(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)^{3/2}} \langle x, y, z \rangle \\
&= G \frac{Mm}{x^2 + y^2 + z^2} \frac{\langle x, y, z \rangle}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2 + z^2}} \\
&= G \frac{Mm}{r^2} \hat{r}
\end{align*}
$$

---

*Really, we should take the *negative* of the gradient, because in physics, we want our force vectors pointing downhill, towards lower energy. But flipping the sign is easy.

Comment: Minor point, the gradient doesn't point uphill, it points in the direction that will lead you uphill. The actual uphill pointing vector will be in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: True, it would. But many people visualize a function from $\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ as being embedded in $\mathbb{R}^3$ already, so it's an easy way to describe it.

Answer (score 1):

The gradient points to the direction of faster growing of the function. See [The Gradient and Directional Derivative](http://math.oregonstate.edu/home/programs/undergrad/CalculusQuestStudyGuides/vcalc/grad/grad.html).